# laravel component attributes value using "dot" character for merge string are not allowed?

Tags: php, laravel, string, merge, laravel-9

first, I have followed all documentation about [components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components). (tell me if I missed something)

Now, i have problems when adding laravel input component attribute value like this:

`tried number 1:`

```
<x-forms.input.text
    value="{{ $datas->product ? $datas->product->code . " - " . $datas->product->name : null }}"
/>
```

it's not working,

but when I change value like this:

`tried number 2:`

```
<x-forms.input.text
    value="{{ $datas->product ? $datas->product->code : null }}"
/>
```

it's working,

my question is:

1. why merge string using "dot" notation not working?
2. are they have best practices to merge string without a "dot" notation?

thanks

laravel version: `9.38.0`

**EDIT**
in view cache, I looking at this: (`tried number 1`)
[image]
when I remove the "dot" notation, they become like this: (`tried number 2`)
[image]

I think the problem is in [image] at "red circle"

Comment: to continue this discussion, I have joined laravel help forum for this issue. here is the link: https://discord.com/channels/297040613688475649/1040510984709750784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in my double quote:

```
value="{{ $datas->product ? $datas->product->code . " - " . $datas->product->name : null }}"
```

that must be a single quote:

```
value="{{ $datas->product ? $datas->product->code . ' - ' . $datas->product->name : null }}"
```

```
                                                 here
```